# Tensorflow estimator fails to converge on model converted from Keras (when using binary_crossentropy)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-estimator, tf.keras

I've been stuck for quite a while using the model_to_estimator functionality in Tensorflow Estimators. The problem seems to be that Keras allows a `binary_crossentropy` loss on a single neuron Dense output.

In my case, I am feeding a RNN sequential data and I want to figure out if the sequence leads to a conversion or not. The code (also to be found at https://colab.research.google.com/drive/194Puigi-LdzxZup6LNREk47l9uP0_Dx9)  for that would be

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

np.random.seed(2)


data = np.random.randint(1,500,size=(10000, 50)) # create something like 50 words out of a vocab of 500


#split
train = data[:7999]
val = data[8000:]

def _input_fn2(arr, batch_size=500, shuffle=False):
  arr_copy = arr.copy()
  def _parse_func(features):   
    sum = tf.math.reduce_sum(features)  

    label = tf.cond(sum >= 15000, lambda: np.array([1]), lambda: np.array([0])) # label=true if sum is larger 15000, gives about 1% true
    return (features, label)

  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(arr_copy)
  dataset = dataset.map(_parse_func)
  dataset = dataset.shuffle(200)
  dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

  dataset = dataset.repeat()  
  return dataset

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input, CuDNNGRU, Embedding
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K


inputs = Input(shape=(50,))

embedding = Embedding(
    output_dim=5,
    input_dim=500,
    input_length=50)(inputs)


lstm = CuDNNGRU(
    units=5,
    input_shape=((5,1)),
    return_sequences=False,
)(embedding)
outputs = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid',name='final')(lstm)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)


def true_positives(y_true, y_pred):
  true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
  return true_positives

def false_positives(y_true, y_pred):
  true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip((1 - y_true) * y_pred, 0, 1)))
  return true_positives

def true_negatives(y_true, y_pred):
  true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip((1 - y_true) * (1 - y_pred), 0, 1)))
  return true_positives

def false_negatives(y_true, y_pred):
  true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * (1 - y_pred), 0, 1)))
  return true_positives

def recall(y_true, y_pred):
  true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
  possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
  recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
  return recall

def precision(y_true, y_pred):
  true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
  predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
  precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
  return precision


model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss='binary_crossentropy', 
    metrics=[
        'acc',
        true_positives,
        true_negatives,
        false_positives,
        false_negatives,
        recall,
        precision
    ]
)
print(model.summary())

train_ds = _input_fn2(train, shuffle=True)
val_ds = _input_fn2(val)
​
model.fit(
    train_ds, 
    steps_per_epoch=50  ,
    epochs=100, 
    validation_data=val_ds,
    validation_steps=10,
    verbose=2
)
```

This works alright, the model converges and starts to learn.

> Epoch 100/100
>    - 2s - loss: 3.5754e-04 - acc: 1.0000 - true_positives: 3.2000 - true_negatives: 496.7400 - false_positives: 0.0000e+00 -
>   false_negatives: 0.0000e+00 - recall: 0.9400 - precision: 0.9400 -
>   val_loss: 0.1281 - val_acc: 0.9806 - val_true_positives: 0.0000e+00 -
>   val_true_negatives: 490.3000 - val_false_positives: 4.5000 -
>   val_false_negatives: 5.2000 - val_recall: 0.0000e+00 - val_precision:
>   0.0000e+00

You can see that mostly it guesses a negative outcome, this is due to the imbalance in the dataset and probably the right thing to do.

Now converting this into an Estimator model like this

```
from tensorflow.keras.estimator import model_to_estimator
from tensorflow.estimator import train_and_evaluate, RunConfig
from tensorflow.estimator import TrainSpec, EvalSpec
from tensorflow import metrics

from tensorflow.contrib.estimator import add_metrics

run_config = RunConfig(
    save_checkpoints_secs=5,
    keep_checkpoint_max=10
)

def eval_metrics(features, labels, predictions):
    return {
        'precision_streaming': metrics.precision(labels=labels, predictions=predictions['final']),
        'recall_streaming': metrics.recall(labels=labels, predictions=predictions['final']),
        'true_positives_streaming': metrics.true_positives(labels=labels, predictions=predictions['final']),
        'true_negatives_streaming': metrics.true_negatives(labels=labels, predictions=predictions['final']),
        'false_positives_streaming': metrics.false_positives(labels=labels, predictions=predictions['final']),
        'false_negatives_streaming': metrics.false_negatives(labels=labels, predictions=predictions['final'])  
    }


estimator = model_to_estimator(keras_model=model, config=run_config)
estimator = add_metrics(estimator, eval_metrics) #took out these metrics for showcase

train_spec = TrainSpec(
  input_fn=lambda: _input_fn2(train, shuffle=True), max_steps=2000 
)


eval_spec = EvalSpec(input_fn=lambda: _input_fn2(val), steps=4)

score = train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)

print(score)
```

After resetting the model and training the Estimator based version, the model doesn't converge but only seems to predict trues now

> ({'binary_accuracy': 0.9865, 'false_negatives_streaming': 0.0, 
>   'false_positives_streaming': 1979.0,  'precision_streaming': 0.0105, 
>   'recall_streaming': 1.0, 'true_negatives_streaming': 0.0, 
>   'true_positives_streaming': 21.0, 'global_step': 2000}, []

Now I managed to get this to work by using a Dense(2) final layer, one-hot encoding the label and switching the loss function to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` ... but I'd really rather keep the single output class as it makes my downstream f1-score and whatnot calculations easier.

An inspired guess would be that the Estimator fails to distribute the loss to the single dense output layer, Keras somehow manages to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Bests wirtsi